# Extra keys being created in code first

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am having an issue where extra fields are being generated in my code first migration and also a relationship I don't want.  I have a basic model, LotteryCarts

```
[Table("lottery_carts")]
public class LotteryCart : Auditable
{
    public LotteryCart()
    {
        LotteryCartItems = new List<LotteryCartItem>();
    }
    //stored in banner: no
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "A lottery is required.")]
    public int LotteryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Lottery Lottery { get; set; }

    public virtual List<LotteryCartItem> LotteryCartItems { get; set; }
}
```

and LotteryCartItem

```
public class LotteryCartItem
{

    [Key, Column(Order=0)]
    public int ClassId { get; set; }
    public virtual Class Class { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int LotteryCartId { get; set; }
    public virtual LotteryCart LotteryCart { get; set; }

    public int BidWeight { get; set; }
    public int order { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}
```

The LotteryCartItem is just a join between LotteryCart and classes (with some extra meta data)

For some reason I don't understand the code first migration is generating extra fields

```
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.LotteryCartItems",
            c => new
                {
                    ClassId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    LotteryCartId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    BidWeight = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    order = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    type = c.String(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.ClassId, t.LotteryCartId })
            .ForeignKey("dbo.classes", t => t.ClassId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.lottery_carts", t => t.LotteryCartId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.ClassId)
            .Index(t => t.LotteryCartId);

        AddColumn("dbo.lottery_carts", "Class_Id", c => c.Int());
        AddColumn("dbo.lottery_carts", "Class_Id1", c => c.Int());
        AddForeignKey("dbo.lottery_carts", "Class_Id", "dbo.classes", "Id");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.lottery_carts", "Class_Id1", "dbo.classes", "Id");
```

I'm  not sure why there is a class_Id and Class_Id1 on lottery_carts, it seems like there is no direct relationship there.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: which version of EF are you using ?

Comment: well, primary key field are not supposed to be nullable!

Comment: @AppDeveloper version 5.
Yeah wow, I changed that! Still no joy.  I originally had a dedicated key field and forgot to un null those when I realized it was not needed!

Comment: @JordanBrooklyn I ran it on my PC and it works fine. The migration does not contain the last four lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LotteryCartItem` should be defined properly

```
public class LotteryCartItem
{

    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [Key, Column(Order=0), ForeignKey("Class")]
    public int ClassId { get; set; }
    public virtual Class Class { get; set; }

    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [Key, Column(Order=1), ForeignKey("LotteryCart")]
    public int LotteryCartId { get; set; }
    public virtual LotteryCart LotteryCart { get; set; }

    public int BidWeight { get; set; }
    public int order { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}
```